Contacts window pops up "by itself"
Since nearly a month the following contact window pops up approx. every hour or so:

The window doesn't seem to belong to a specific application, but when it pops up it steals the focus and keyboard input is eaten by it until I either click into the previous app or close the contact window with ESC.
The window is free floating (despite the pointy bit on the left!) and it can float above any app's windows. Here an example where it floats over my Vivaldi browser window:

I have no idea whatsoever where this pop up comes from. Does anybody know more?
I'm running macOS 14.5 on a MacMini M2
Many thanks for any pointers!

How annoying. What is to the left of that window? The dock?

Yes, what is the pointy bit on the left pointing to?

@bmike No, the window is free floating. Nothing particular to its left. - I'll add another screenshot to the question to illustrate this.

@benwiggy No, the window is free floating (despite the pointy bit on the left!), The window can float above any app's windows.

I don't know what this can be other than some third-party software that runs in the background. Open the Login Items panel in System Settings and look over the list headed "Allow in the Background". It may be obvious what the suspects are, for example if one of them has a name such as "Irritating Popups 4U"; if so, disable them and test. Otherwise, disable half of them at a time, then the other half, until you isolate the culprit.

@LincD. Thanks for the detailed suggestion. I guess that's unfortunately the way I need to go -- if nobody else has experienced this and knows already the fix.

It may sound silly but have you tried restarting your Mac? That's often a fix to this kind of annoying problems.

@Thinkr Actually, I have restarted now -- and the Contacts window hasn't poped up so far. Let's see how it goes

This isn't based on specific knowledge of how apps can interact with Contacts, but if the problem returns and Linc D.'s advice doesn't solve it, I would try a similar approach with "Settings > Privacy and Security > Contacts > Allow the applications below to access your contacts."

@Thinkr Your "silly-sounding" suggestion was probably the closest to what helped. Do you want to write it as an answer? We have 18 hours for me to give you the bounty...

@halloleo Well, glad that worked ;) Okay, I can put that as an answer.

@Thinkr There you are. Done. Thanks.

A simple restart of your Mac is likely to resolve the problem. It's often a fix to this kind of issues. :)

This did the trick. However as a disclaimer I need to add that I had disallowed (but after restart reenabled) a lot of background permissions in Settings -> Privacy. This might have affected the result as well.
